# "File" backed by running program?

Tags: files, filesystems

My clients have many programs that read and write files of a certain format. They do it by sending regular old system calls, so libraries like gio aren't (in the general case) involved. I would like store the data in a database instead of the files, although I can't change the programs that read and write the files. Instead, I need to store the data in a database while tricking the programs into *thinking* they are reading and writing files.

One potential solution would be to have some kind of pseudo-file, where all of the read, write and seek requests get re-directed to a program I could write, which could then synthesize the correct response via communication with the database. This task sounds vaguely like NFS, so maybe it's possible. What should I read about to get this working?

Comment: That depends from what operating system you are using.  Is it based upon the Hurd?  Solaris?  Linux?  FreeBSD?

Comment: Even if they don't use GIO, if the gvfs fuse Daemon is running, you'll still be able to access gvfs mounts using regular system calls (e.g. you can run plain old `cp` on gvfs files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). User mode file-systems. They look like file-systems but have custom internals.

Some existing ones are:

- sshfs file-system over ssh.
- tar / zip fs mount a tar / zip file.
- cloud fs
- ipfs
- ntfs
- encrypted fs
- webdav
- ftp
- amazon S3